# How to refresh ads or page when visitor stays for longer duration in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

This code refreshes an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        setInterval(refreshiframe, 5000);
    });

    function refreshiframe() {
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
    }

</script>
```

Is it possible to refresh a div containing ads or page in background? to get more pageviews per visitor?

Comment: SO help with code you wrote, not write it for you. Make an effort of your own and come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Look at .load()